# How to show a growing sub view over a parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiview-hierarchy

I have a view as follows

[image: Parent View]

The colored tiles are basically views. When i long press on the tiled views i am creating a copy of the tile in which it was long pressed. Also when it is long pressed there should be a view as per the following image.

[image]

The drop area should come up from bottom part or it should grow from bottom insect of the screen.

When long pressing on the tiled view i am creating a copy of the view and i am able to make the copy successfully and drag on the screen, but i am stuck at creation of this drop area and its animation.

Can someone guide me how to implement this....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you're not able to code the drop area? or what's the problem exacty?

Comment: to implement the drop area to have a growing effect you should do 3 things in animation code, first increase its width to entire screen, reduce the y coordinate to bring the view up on the screen, and finally add to the current hieght so that it covers bottom area of your screen.

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani I am not able to generate the drop area programmatically. Thats where i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let dropView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:300, height:100))
    dropView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height)
    dropView.center = CGPoint(x:self.view.frame.size.width/2, y:dropView.center.y)
    dropView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.view.addSubview(dropView)
```

When you want to animate it to show up use this:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
        dropView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:dropView.frame.origin.x, y:dropView.frame.origin.y - dropView.frame.size.width - 10)
    }, completion: nil)
```